# What would be php equivalent of this code?

Tags: php, javascript, regex, equivalent

```
var okTags = /^(<\/?(b|blockquote|code|del|dd|dl|dt|em|h1|h2|h3|i|kbd|li|ol|p|pre|s|sup|sub|strong|strike|ul)>|<(br|hr)\s?\/?>)$/i;

var okLinks = /^(<a\shref="(\#\d+|(https?|ftp):\/\/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+)"(\stitle="[^"<>]+")?\s?>|<\/a>)$/i;


var okImg = /^(<img\ssrc="https?:(\/\/[-A-Za-z0-9+&@#\/%?=~_|!:,.;\(\)]+)"(\swidth="\d{1,3}")?(\sheight="\d{1,3}")?(\salt="[^"<>]*")?(\stitle="[^"<>]*")?\s?\/?>)$/i;


text = text.replace(/<[^<>]*>?/gi, function (tag) {
                    return (tag.match(okTags) || tag.match(okLinks) || tag.match(okImg)) ? tag : ""
                })
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`replace()` can be replaced by [preg_replace()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-replace.php)

and `match()` would be [preg_match()](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.preg-match.php) which is very powerful

Check the manual to see how it would work with your code, they are not that different, and you can use your call back function too.

Comment: `preg_replace_callback()` would be the suitable replacement in this case.

Answer (score 2):

It looks like you are parsing HTML with regex.

In that case, PHP provides [DOMDocument](http://php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) which is pretty good for doing DOM manipulation. You *could* use it ensure your string contains *safe* HTML.

A more domain specific solution is [HTML Purifier](http://htmlpurifier.org/).